# DIV containing a SWF

Tags: html, css, flash

I have a  tag to include add a SWF but I would like  around it to control it's size.

I have something like the following:

```
<div style="left: 852px; top: 596px; width: 30px; height: 20px;">
    <embed align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" wmode="transparent" quality="high" style="overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

But unfortunately, the embed tag (SWF) expands from the DIV. I thought overflow:hidden would assure that it does not.

How can I fix this issue please?

Thank you very much,

Rudy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `overflow:hidden;` on the parent div, the one with dimensions defined.